# Example of 3 nonlinear points such that no square passes through all 3 points

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry

I know that for any 3 nonlinear point there exists circle which passes through that points.

I wanted to know is this fact true for square .

Can any one help me to give counterexample

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: A line passes through two points, and a perpendicular line to this one through the third point .

Comment: Take the distance of two furthest from each other points as the length of your square.  Then these two points will lie on the opposite sides of the square which are parallel to the  perpendicular drawn from the third point to the line between first two points.

Comment: @Lee then also a square exists with different side length

Comment: Related : http://www.hep.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/4point.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may help to consider the three points as vertices of a triangle.

If the triangle is isosceles, with acute vertex angle at $C$, as in the first figure, draw a line through $B$ parallel to $AC$. Then draw $AE$, $CD$ perpendicular to that line, make $EF=GD=ED$ and complete square $EDGF$. This construction works also if $ABC$ is equilateral.[image: isosceles with short base]

If the angle at $C$ is right, $AB$ is the diagonal of a square easy to complete.

If the angle at $C$ is obtuse, as in the second figure, draw a line through $C$ parallel to base $AB$, and complete the square as before.[image: isosceles with obtuse vertex angle]

Lastly, if triangle $ABC$ is scalene, as in the third figure, draw a line through the vertex of the greatest angle, parallel to the longest side of the triangle (here a line through $C$ parallel to $AB$), and complete the square. [image: scalene triangle]

Thus it seems that, given three non-collinear points, a square can be constructed such that the three points lie on its perimeter.

Comment: See my new solution (I have abandoned the old one).

Comment: Shouldn't the third figure just work for all cases? I don't see why the other cases are necessary. (And I'm pretty sure you're drawing the same square in th other cases, too.)

Comment: @Misha Lavrov--I think you are right; essentially the construction is "Draw a parallel through the vertex opposite the triangle's greatest side, then perpendiculars to the parallel from the triangle's other two vertices, and complete the square." I studied the isosceles cases first, but the scalene covers it all.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof avoiding to consider different figure cases.

Consider the figure below. For a given orientation $\theta$ and its orthogonal orientation $\theta+\pi/2$, we obtain 2 "minimal covering stripes" of triangle $ABC$, with red lines limits and blue lines limits resp. with widths $W_{\theta}$ and $W_{\theta+\pi/2}$ resp. 
If, for a given orientation $\theta$, $$S_{\theta}>S_{\theta+\pi/2}\tag{1}$$ (as is the case on the given figure), replacing $\theta$ by $\theta+\pi/2$ results in the reversal of order in (1). As functions $W_{\theta}$ and $W_{\theta+\pi/2}$ are continuous functions of angle $\theta$, there exists $\theta_0$ with $\theta<\theta_0<\theta+\pi/2$ where the widths are equal !

[image]

Comment: This seems a good approach, and uses only one figure.  Mine would probably be better (more economical) had it considered only the scalene case, as the @Misha Lavrov comment points out.

Comment: @Edward Porcella I agree !

Answer (score 0):

Consider the 3 random non co-linear points $A$, $B$ and $C$ :

[image]

Now if we join $AC$ and draw the $\perp$  from $B$ to$AC$

[image]

Now since $BD > AC$, we can construct a square of side length $BD$. So extend $AC$ such that $l(AE)=l(BD)$

[image]

Now if we draw square with side $AE$ such that it contains $B$ by drawing respective perpendiculars.

[image]

We have a square $AEFG$ (one of many) that passes through $A$, $B$, $C$ : 3 non-co-linear points.

So there will be at least 1 square that passes through 3 non-co-linear (or even co-linear points for that matter).